# Use R to create differently sized graphs with same text size

Tags: r, graph

I need to create small and large versions of several graphs such that the text size is the same. I'd like to avoid fiddling with low-level graphical parameters, but so far that's the only thing that's worked for me, and even that hasn't worked perfectly.

Here's what I have now. It basically relies on setting the cex for the smaller graphs to the same ratio as that of the smaller image to the larger image size, and then setting the cex for all text appearing in the smaller graphs to the inverse of that ratio.

```
# actual data to be plotted
x       = seq( 1, 10, 0.01 )
B       = 1.0
a       = 1.0
y       = B*(x^((-1)*a))

# set graphical parameters
xlim    = c(0,10)
ylim    = c(0,5)
xlab    = "Number of repetitions"
ylab    = "Time in seconds"
version = "large" # or "small"
if ( version=="large" ) {
    w = 800
    h = 510
} else if ( version=="small" ) {
    w = 266
    h = 170
}

# create the actual plots
# I tried to remove unnecessary details but leave those that might matter for my question
png( paste(version,".png",sep=""), width=w, height=h )
par( las=1 )
if ( version=="large" ) {
    plot( 0, 0, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab, col=rgb(0,0,0,0) )
    lines(spline(x,y, method='n', n=1000), lwd=3 )
} else if ( version=="small" ) {
    par( cex=1/3, mar=c(8,8,1,1) )
    plot( 0, 0, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, col=rgb(0,0,0,0), axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="", frame.plot=TRUE )
    lines(spline(x,y, method='n', n=1000), lwd=2 )
    axis( side=1, cex.axis=3, mgp=c(5.5,2.5,0) )
    title( xlab=xlab, cex.lab=3, mgp=c(5.5,2.5,0) )
    axis( side=2, cex.axis=3, mgp=c(5,2,0) )
    title( ylab=ylab, cex.lab=3, mgp=c(5,2,0) )
}
dev.off()
```

This works OK but I had to spend a lot of time hand-coding the character expansions and margins, and even after I finished doing that, it still only solves my problem for the specific example shown. When I change almost any detail, e.g. if the labels on the y-axis become wider than they are now because they are 2 digits long instead of 1, I have to go back and handcraft new settings again. It's horrible! How can I make this happen automatically without having to handcraft low-level details?

By the way, I'm eventually going to want to make the plot lines antialiased so I'd appreciate it if the proposed solution doesn't make that impossible. E.g. I saw somewhere that I can use cairoDevice to antialias, and might be able to use ggplot to resolve my sizing issues, but not sure whether I can do both at the same time? Need to antialias might be removed by using pdf instead of png but I want to display as images in a webpage so I think I need png. Saving large and displaying small does not work well for png format as I understand.

Comment: Apologies - fixed now.

Comment: here Can you precise what do you want to automate? `par( cex=1/3, mar=c(8,8,1,1) )`? `mgp=c(5.5,2.5,0)`??

Comment: Hm, I'll try, but it goes against the grain because my desire is to find a method that handles the details for me so I *don't* have to think about what they are. Anyway, to answer your question, at a minimum I would like to have the size of margins and distances between elements like axes, axis ticks, axis numbers, and axis labels be automated to come out reasonably regardless of the size of the whole graph and the text font. "Reasonable" means not overlapping, not flying off the side of the graph, etc.